# How to pass 2D int array to another activity C#

Tags: c#, arrays, android-intent, xamarin, multidimensional-array

I want to pass a 2D integer array to another activity. I have tried with various way.

- Convert my int 2d array (state) to string 2d array (converted_array)

  ```
  string[,] converted_array = new string[10, 10];

  //convert the state array to string, for the intent
  for (int i = 0; i <= GlobalVariables.total_row; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j <= GlobalVariables.total_column; j++)
      {
          converted_array[i, j] = state[i, j].ToString();
      }
  }
  //create my intent
  var step_by_step = new Intent(this, typeof(step_by_step));
  Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
  mBundle.PutSerializable("array",converted_array); //<--- here, error (impossible to convert string[*,*] to java.io.iserializable
  ```

In which way I can pass this 2D array?

**My solution** (thank you to @SushiHangover)

Put in a Global Variable my int 2D array like this:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
    {
        public static int[,] state_global = new int[10, 10];
    }

GlobalVariables.state_global = state;
```

Comment: Hav you tried with `string[][]` instead of `string[,]`? and also, seems you don't need to convert it to string since it's already `int` and I believe int array is already supported.

Comment: i don't want an array of array (string[][]) but a multidimensial array(string[,]). i have tried also with int 2D array but return the same mistake.

Comment: Xamarin can convert/serialize basic types from C# to a Java-based `ISerializable` automatically, the *quickest* way would be to convert your array to Json and serialize the `string`, or implement an `ISerializable` subclass to parcel/unparcel your object, or store the object publicly at the `Application` level, etc...

Comment: thank you @SushiHangover! i did not think about global variables....now with my int 2D array in a global variable all work well